# How to get chromecast support working with the new androidx libraries

Tags: google-cast

I had the chromecast working following the guide at https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender/integrate. But recently I upgraded to androidx as that seemed the way to got. This meant that

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/media_route_menu_item"
    android:title="@string/media_route_menu_title"
    app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

got changed to

```
<item android:id="@+id/media_route_menu_item" 
    android:title="@string/media_route_menu_title"
    app:actionProviderClass="androidx.mediarouter.app.MediaRouteActionProvider"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

But otherwise, all stays the same for example still CastButtonFactory is used to make the connections. I don't see any button appearing anymore so not sure what is wrong. I still implement AppCompat, have the CastOptions, execute CastContext.getSharedInstance(this). Logging for cast discovery has always been very limited to it is hard to know what is going on.

Comment: You may need to make the changes in the .java files from
import android.support.v7.media.MediaRouteSelector;
import android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter;
import android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter.Callback;
import android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter.RouteInfo;                   to
import androidx.mediarouter.media.MediaRouteSelector;
import androidx.mediarouter.media.MediaRouter;
import androidx.mediarouter.media.MediaRouter.Callback;
import androidx.mediarouter.media.MediaRouter.RouteInfo;

Comment: Thx for your suggestion. As I replaced the gradle dependencies, of course I also changed the imports. wouldn't compile otherwise.

Comment: Even I had the same issue, what worked for me is I used the light theme and the controls will be black since the appTheme is light I changed the theme for cromeCast activity and expandedcontrols activity then I'm able to see the icons